# Retrofit Post: Getting slashes when sending request

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I am working on Retrofit Post but i am getting slashes () when sending data to post method. Here i need to send the complete json object data to post method, so i  converted the json object to String . But when sending slashes are appending to request. I also replaced the  slashes to empty string but it is not working. Any one please help me.

code:

```
 private void favouriteadding(String restaurant_id, String restaurant_name, JsonArray Restaurant_info) {
        String replac = Restaurant_info.toString(); // jsonarray
        replac = replac.replace("[", "")
                .replace("]", "")
                .trim();
        Log.v("Tag_replacestring",""+replac);
        ServiceClient serviceClient = ServiceUtil.getServiceClient();
        JsonObject userfav = new JsonObject();
        userfav.addProperty("user_id", m_sharedPreference.getString("userid", ""));
        userfav.addProperty("restaurant_id", restaurant_id);
        userfav.addProperty("restaurant_name", restaurant_name);
        userfav.addProperty("restaurant_info",replac.replace('\\','"') );
        Log.v("Tag_postdata",""+userfav);
        serviceClient.list_fav(userfav, listfavcallback);
    }
```

Log:

```
 Tag_replacestring:   {"status":"enabled","features":"No Alcohol Available","cuisines":"Hyderabadi","Mughlai","Biryani","Chinese","cost":850.0,"createdAt":"2018-03-08 09:26:13","branch_id":"5aa146ce1d41c86e73e11d79","stats":{},"dishes":"Hyderabadi Dum Biryani","Mutton Biryani}
```

but getting like this with slashes:
Tag_postdata:

```
{"user_id":"","restaurant_id":"5aa148051d41c86e73e11d7a","restaurant_name":"Hotel Shadab","restaurant_info":"{\"status\":\"enabled\",\"features\":\"No Alcohol Available\",\"cuisines\":\"Hyderabadi\",\"Mughlai\",\"Biryani\",\"Chinese\",\"cost\":850.0,\"createdAt\":\"2018-03-08 09:26:13\",\"branch_id\":\"5aa146ce1d41c86e73e11d79\"
```

Comment: Rectify Json .Invalid JSON variable

Comment: whats your json response?

Comment: @kdblue response ok. here they are sending what i sent. They again sending response with slashes